# How can I save my video to a special folder in the photo album?

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, avassetwriter

I have an iPhone app that streams video to our Wowza server.

I'd like to implement a new feature that collects my video frames and on completion, saves that recording to a local folder, which will be specially titled and stored in the device's photo album. I have explored AVAssetWriter and UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum, but I am not sure how to create a new folder (if there isn't one already) and save the videos there.

A high level answer or code example will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create custom albums(Folders) in user's photo app. You only have access to the default album of it which is Camera Roll.